# Move a rectangle using arrow keys

Tags: java, keylistener, keyevent

I am trying to develop a simple game where you can move a rectangle using the left and right arrow keys and to shoot using the spacebar.

I have added a `KeyListener` and others, but when I run it I have nothing as the output of key pressed or others.

I have two classes:

**PaintDemo class:**

```
package game;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PaintDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Game 1.1");
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setBounds(10, 10, 400, 400);
        mainFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        PaintComponent paintPanel = new PaintComponent();

        mainFrame.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        mainFrame.add(paintPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        mainFrame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

**PaintComponent class:**

```
package game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class PaintComponent extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
    int dx = 200;
    int dy = 300;
    int my = 300;
    public Rectangle2D rec = new Rectangle2D.Double(dx , dy, 30, 10);

    public PaintComponent() {
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        this.setBackground(Color.white);
    }

    public void shoot(KeyEvent evt){
        if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
        my -= 7;
        repaint();
        }
    }

    public void moveRec(KeyEvent evt){
        switch(evt.getKeyCode()){
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                System.out.println("test");
                dx -= 2;
                rec.setRect(dx, dy, 30, 10);
                repaint();
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                dx += 2;
                rec.setRect(dx, dy, 30, 10);
                repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics grphcs){
        super.paintComponent(grphcs);
        Graphics2D gr = (Graphics2D) grphcs;
        gr.draw(rec);
    }


    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("2");
        shoot(e);
    }


    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        moveRec(e);

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }
}
```

The shooting method is not complete.

Comment: So what happens when you press left, or right? Does the rectangle move?

Comment: no nothing is happening!

Comment: Is the rectangle displayed?

Comment: yes the rectangle is visible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change repaint() to paintComponent here and add Graphics g = getGraphics();

```
public void moveRec(KeyEvent evt){
    switch(evt.getKeyCode()){
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            System.out.println("test");
            dx -= 2;
            rec.setRect(dx, dy, 30, 10);
            Graphics g = getGraphics();
            paintComponent(g);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            dx += 2;
            rec.setRect(dx, dy, 30, 10);
            Graphics g = getGraphics();
            paintComponent(g);
            break;
    }
}
```

Let me know if this works :)

EDIT:
Add this line

```
this.setFocusable(true);
```

to PaintComponent constructor, it will make keypresses go through.

Comment: I don't know how to apply this change!

Comment: Nothing's happened! :(
I have written system.out.println("test") to test if my keylistener is working!
and it's not! I mean it doesn't write the "test"!

Comment: I applied the changes, it doesn't work!
case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            System.out.println("test");
            dx -= 2;
            rec.setRect(dx, dy, 30, 10);
            Graphics g = getGraphics();
            paintComponent(g);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            dx += 2;
            rec.setRect(dx, dy, 30, 10);
            Graphics g2 = getGraphics();
            paintComponent(g2);
            break;

Comment: I had to rename the second graphic in case 2 to g2! is it all right?!

Comment: Yes. Did you add "this.setFocusable(true);" to PaintComponent constructor?

Comment: IT WORKED!!!! :D I made a mistake and I have added setfocusable() in my paintdemo class before!!! Thank YOU So much!

Comment: Kindly consider voting up my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to do two things, First one is your panel should be focusable, add this in your `PaintComponent` constructor `this.setFocusable(true)` and the second one is you have not `break` the switch case, so add the `break` statement for each case, then it should work.

```
switch (evt.getKeyCode()) {
case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
    System.out.println("test");
    dx -= 2;
    rec.setRect(dx, dy, 30, 10);
    repaint();
    break;
case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
    dx += 2;
    rec.setRect(dx, dy, 30, 10);
    repaint();
    break;
}
```

Comment: did you add the setFocusable(true)

Comment: did you add that in the `PaintComponent` constructor?

Comment: IT WORKED!!!! :D I made a mistake and I have added setfocusable() in my paintdemo class before!!! Thank YOU So much!